# Ignored \bigskip and extra blank line

Tags: vertical-spacing

In the short tex file below compiled with TeXShop 4.68, you can see that my \bigskip on line 8 is ignored (no vertical space between the title and the text) ; also the last-but-one line in the output is a blank line I didn't ask for in the source.
Where does this come from ? How may I fix it ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,nohead,foot=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\bigskip
\noindent{\large\bf Kyrie} (p. 91)\newline
\bigskip
Kyrie, eleison. Christe, eleison. Kyrie, eleison. (3x3)\newline
\bigskip
{\large\bf Gloria} (p. 92)\newline
\bigskip
Gloria in excelsis Deo ; et in terra pax hominibus bonae voluntatis.\newline
Laudamus te.\newline
\end{document}
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: the `\bigskip` isn't ignored, it causes the vertical space after the first line, as you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note `\bf` should not be used (it is not defined by default in latex, although some classes define it for compatibility with documents from the 1980s)

You are using `\bigskip` in horizontal mode mid-paragraph so it is saved (in a vadjust node) and the vertical space added after the line in which the command was issued.

You probably wanted to add the space at that point, so remove the `\newline` commands and replace by a blank line, then the paragraph will end and `\bigskip` will be seen in vertical mode and add space at that point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,nohead,foot=0.5cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\large Kyrie} (p. 91)

Kyrie, eleison. Christe, eleison. Kyrie, eleison. (3x3)

\textbf{\large Gloria} (p. 92)

Gloria in excelsis Deo ; et in terra pax hominibus bonae voluntatis.

Laudamus te.
\end{document}
```

Here I specified (parskip package) that paragraphs should not be indented but should be separated by vertical space so `\noindent`, `\newline` and `\bigskip` markup dropped from each instance.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If `bf` is not to be used, what should I replace it with ?

Comment: @user40960 a latex command such as `\textbf` or `\bfseries` (`\bf` isn't even mentioned in the latex book)  I put an example in the answer

Comment: Well, `\bf` is mentioned as a standard in my dog-eared, obsolete LaTeX manual from another era ... :-)

Comment: @user40960 as I say, some classes define it for compatibility with documents from before 1993, the latex format hasn't defined it since then, seems like only yesterday...

Comment: @user40960 actually I guess the Laudamus te. isn't a new paragraph so remove that blank line and add `\\ ` after  `voluntatis.` if you want a forced line break (or `\newline` is same thing as `\\ `)